# Menu Bar app being launched by Dock Icon (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, icons, menubar, dock

I'm working on a Menu Bar app and I've added the LSUIElement so the icon won't appear in the dock when the app is in use (And also to remove the File, Edit, View etc at the left of the menu bar).

The problem is that I want the app to be launched by the Icon and by adding the LSUIElement the only way to luanch the app is thru xcode.

I've seen that in the Mac app Caffiene it launches by the icon but it doesn't appear in the dock that it's running etc which is excatly what I want/need.

So I was wondering if you guys know how to do this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Surely you would just build the application, put it in the /Applications folder and then launch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a dock icon but not show the app as running in the Dock, simply create two applications:

**Status Menu Application**

This is the actual application that sets up the menu and contains the application's logic. It has `LSUIElement` set.

**Launcher Application**

This application has a dock icon. It contains the status menu application in its bundle. Its sole job is to launch the status menu application and then quit itself.

Comment: Do you have any example code of how to create a Launcher Application ?

Comment: @Sweppi There's nothing fancy about it ... simply create a new Cocoa app with the icon you want, put the other app that you want to launch into its bundle, and when the launcher app is launched, launch the other app that you have in the bundle (e.g. `-[NSWorkspace launchApplicationAtURL:options:configuration:error:]`), and terminate the launcher app.

Comment: Should it be the builded app or the project and everything that is added to the bundle? If it's the builded only, where do I find it? I can't find a build folder or anything inside of the project folders like I do on the iOS apps. 

And sorry for all questions, I'm still learning :(

Comment: Only add the finished status menu app (not the project). You'll want to set up your project so it first builds the status menu app, either as a second target, or as a project in the same Workspace (Xcode 4) or subproject (Xcode 3). Then copy the app to the bundle of your launcher app using a copy files build phase that contains the status menu app (by default, finished builds are in the "Products" folder of your project).

Answer (score 0):

There is a really simple way to do this without creating a separate launcher app. Build your application, which has a status item, as an app bundle. Then, add an entry to the application's Info.plist file

```
Key: NSUIElement
Value: Number, 1 or Boolean True
```

NSUIElement tells OSX if the app should display in the Dock or not.